# Custom shape registers taps outside drawn path

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-view

I created a custom `Arc` shape in SwiftUI, but when I add an `onTapGesture` modifier to it, it registers taps outside the area I drew for the `Arc` (it registers taps *anywhere* within the `rect` used to draw the `Arc`). How can I make sure the taps only register *within* the drawn path of the `Arc`, not the entire `rect`?

Here's the `Arc` shape I drew:

```
struct Arc: Shape {
  let angle: Angle
  let thickness: CGFloat
  let clockwise: Bool
  
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    
    let innerArcEndPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - thickness, y: 0)
    let innerArcStartPoint = CGPoint(
      x: innerArcEndPoint.x * cos(CGFloat(angle.radians)),
      y: innerArcEndPoint.x * sin(CGFloat(angle.radians)))
    
    path.move(to: innerArcStartPoint)
    path.addArc(center: rect.origin, radius: innerArcEndPoint.x, startAngle: angle, endAngle: Angle.zero, clockwise: !clockwise)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: 0))
    path.addArc(center: rect.origin, radius: rect.maxX, startAngle: Angle.zero, endAngle: angle, clockwise: clockwise)
    path.closeSubpath()
    
    return path
  }
}
```

Here's me using the `Arc` with an `onTapGesture` modifier:

```
struct TestTappingArc: View {
    var body: some View {
        Arc(angle: Angle(degrees: 45), thickness: 20, clockwise: false)
          .foregroundColor(.blue) // The only area I want to be tappable
          .background(Color.orange) // The area I DON'T want to be tappable (but currently is tappable)
          .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
          .onTapGesture {
            print("hello")
          }
    }
}
```

And here's what it looks like on screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Asperi for that answer--that does fix the problem. However, I realized an even simpler solution is just to move the background to *after* the `onTapGesture` modifier, like this:

```
Arc(angle: Angle(degrees: 45), thickness: 20, clockwise: false)
  .foregroundColor(.blue)
  .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
  .onTapGesture {
    print("hello")
  }
  .background(Color.orange)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `contentShape` with same shape to restrict hit-testing area (because view is always rectangular), like

```
Arc(angle: Angle(degrees: 45), thickness: 20, clockwise: false)
  .foregroundColor(.blue)
  .contentShape(Arc(angle: Angle(degrees: 45), thickness: 20, clockwise: false))
  .onTapGesture {      // << here !!
    print("hello")
  }
  .background(Color.orange)
  .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```